# How to submit a form by using both submit button and enter key

Tags: jquery

How can I submit a form by using both submit button and enter key?

I tried by using this code but I don't know how to use both enter key and submit button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(){
    //validating first name
    if ($(!"#first").val() == '') {
      $("#error_msg").empty().text("First name should not empty");
      if ($("#first").val().match(/^([a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)*){1,70}$/)) {
        $("#error_msg").empty().text("");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you place an `<input type="submit" />` or `<button type="submit">` *within* the `<form>` tag you'll get this behaviour by default - no need for JS interference

Comment: Also... instead of nesting `if` conditionals, put them at the same level and simply `return false` in each statement.